# What bazel build command can be used for genrule with loop?

Tags: bazel

What build command I can use for below `genrule`?

This `genrule` might be evaluated multiply and each `genrule` have a unique name so that I'm wondering what I configured target name for bazel build.

I hope the `genrule` is built multiply by a single build command.

```
[genrule(
  name = "gen_txt_" + fin,
  srcs = [":sources"],
  outs = [fin + ".cp"],
  cmd = """
  cp $@ $@.cp
  """,
) for fin in glob(["*.in"])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from the `Bazel` User's guide.

- https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/guide.html#specifying-targets-to-build

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).